# Can I rearrange the given names of authors in Pubmed for importing to EndNote?

Tags: reference-managers, pubmed

When viewing a Pubmed citation, author names are listed in the format `Surname Initial Initial`.  This means that when I am inputting a citation into EndNote I have to either type the names in manually or copy and paste then edit the order of the names into the `Initial Initial Surname` format that EndNote accepts.

E.g. the Pubmed author list:

> Frayling TM, Timpson NJ, Weedon MN

Would need to be rearranged to

> TM Frayling
>
> NJ Timpson
>
> MN Weedon

by hand in EndNote.

Is there a way that I can do this more efficiently?  Perhaps by

- Using a preference on PubMed to have authors displayed in the second way
- Modifying a preference in EndNote to have it accept the first way
- Using a more efficient way to record new items to the EndNote database

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Why would anyone enter reference from PubMed into EndNote **by hand**? You can connect EndNote to PubMed and download the reference, and the author list should be arrange as `Surename, initials`.

Answer (score 1):

Just import the reference as Pubmed outputs it and then change the output style within Endnote to match your preferred format. If it's a standard format for a well known journal, you should be able to directly select that output style, otherwise, you can make a custom format using the formatting code for the style you want. There are several online guides out there that give details how to do that.  Examples:

http://libguides.usd.edu/content.php?pid=63203&sid=755800

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbq-naXl8r4  (see ~8mins in)